# How are the resources distributed for several replicas for docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I think I am just missing minor detail but it seems a documentation is little unclear to me. So the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas) states that,

> If the service is replicated (which is the default), specify the number of containers that should be running at any given time.

now if use a [resource limit](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) for the service e.g.

```
replicas: 2
resources:
  limits:
    cpus: '0.50'
    memory: 50M
```

Does that imply that each replica gets 0.5 of each core or does the sum of replica get 0.5 of one core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits are applied to each replica. For the overall cluster utilization limit, you would multiply by the number of replicas.